# File.ReadAllBytes execution hangs in Docker container

Tags: .net, docker, containers

This is .Net framework 4.7.2 console app, build platform x64, build in release mode.

OS Windows 10, Docker desktop 2.1.0.5

When running in windows container, the program hangs at File.ReadAllBytes, while reading a 130 MB binary file. This file copied into assembly folder, also get copied into container. File.Exists verified the file is there.
The program runs fine to the end when running directly in command prompt, outside container.

Please help.

Dockerfile

> FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime-windowsservercore-1803
>
> ARG source
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> COPY ${source:-bin/Release} .
>
> CMD ["fileread-docker.exe"]

Code

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine("folder", "a.abc");
            Console.WriteLine($"Read file from {path}");
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"File exist at {path}");
                var file = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                Console.WriteLine($"File has been read at {path}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"File not exist at {path}");
            }
        }
    }
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's base image issue.

It's working after I switch
from

> FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime-windowsservercore-1803

to

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8

New base image is ridiculously 14 GB big. Previously was 6.4GB.

Anyway, this new base image works as expected. Previous image was copied from one sample code.

Comment: According to dotnet-framework-docker team

"The main issue when it comes to the size of the .NET Framework images is the base OS image. The Windows team has been working to address the size of the base OS images since they were initially release via ltsc2016. You can easily see this by pulling and checking the size of the base images. If you are looking for the smallest image, your best option is to go with the latest - 1909"